# How to construct API URL using POST method

Tags: php, html, api

We use Lansweeper for our helpdesk. Lansweeper has an API to submit a ticket. It requires 3 or 4 values. I have a page on our intranet site for the user to input the required information. According to the API documentation it has to be a POST request. Here is the form

```
<form action="http://lansweeper:81/api.aspx" method="post">
            
                <input type ="hidden" name="Action" value="AddTicket">
                <input type="hidden" name="Key" value="80aac06c-43c1-498a-9e0f-d477e398b13b">
                
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="Username">
                <br>
                <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="subject" name="Subject">
                <br>
                <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="emailaddr" name="Email">
                <br>
                <br>
                <label for="Description">Please enter a short description of your issue:</label>
                <br>
                <textarea name="Description" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Ticket" name="submit">
</form>
```

If I use GET as the method I can see the URL looks like the below and I get a 500 internal server error from the browser http://lansweeper:81/api.aspx?Action=AddTicket&Key=80aac06c-43c1-498a-9e0f-d477e398b13b&Username=test&Subject=test&Email=test@test.com&Description=test&submit=Submit+Ticket but if I use POST it just returns the http://lansweeper:81/api.aspx and a 500 internal server error.

Here is a sample URL from the API documentation: http://YourServerName:81/api.aspx?Action=AddTicket&Key=123456789&Subject=Example&Description=Example&Type=Hardware&Priority=High&Username=MyDomain\Earl&AgentUsername=MyDomain\John&Team=Information%20Technology

Since I have to use POST, would I need to change the form action instead to a different php file that does some logic to send the values to the API?

Comment: An HTML form automatically sends all the input fields as parameters to the server script. I think you need to read a tutorial on processing forms with PHP.

Comment: 500 internal error also implies a bug.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar said, form submit functionality automatically passes form values to the action. So you would have your form action set to the Lansweeper endpoint, and a button `type=“submit”` on the form. When submit is clicked, the form values are passed for Lansweeper to handle.

Comment: Hi, I tried having the lansweeper endpoint as the form action but that didn't work.I have added my code to show what I am doing. is there any other suggestions you may be able to add?

Comment: In comparing the error returned from your get request to the documentation, it looks like the parameters are different. Is it possible that you’re not sending the right fields? If that’s not the case, I would think maybe the action is incorrect. I assumed that Lansweeper would provide a handler for the submission, but maybe you have to create your own?

Comment: what appears different for the parameters? I keep looking over the documentation and it appears I am using the right fields. In my example I am only using the required fields. Lansweeper, at least on the documentation page does not provide a handler. not really sure what that is. but I found some api testing sites and the basic http:lansweeper:81/api.aspx doesn't work. DNS error: No such host. I emailed lansweeper support as I suspect maybe there's an issue elsewhere